# Using Core Location on my iPod touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-location

i have been trying to implement the following code on my device:-

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
 @interface Whereami1ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
  {
      CLLocationManager *locationManager;

      __weak IBOutlet UILabel *coordLabel;
  }
 @end

 @implementation Whereami1ViewController

 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
  {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
          // Custom initialization
             locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
              [locationManager setDelegate:self];

             [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
             locationManager.distanceFilter= 5.00;//5 meters

             [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


         }
         return self;
       }

       -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray  *)locations{//location manager sends this message to self
          NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
           NSLog(@"new location–– %@",[locations lastObject]);
           NSLog(@"latitude= %f, longitude= %f",[[locations lastObject] coordinate].latitude, [[locations lastObject] coordinate].longitude);
          CGSize coordData= {[[locations lastObject] coordinate].latitude, [[locations lastObject] coordinate].longitude};

          coordLabel.text= NSStringFromCGSize(coordData);//setting the label's text

       }
       -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
           NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
           NSLog(@"location not found: %@", error);
       }
       @end
```

In the code i have set the distance filter as 5 meters. This means after 5 meters worth of movement the device goes through, it should be updating the label's text to a new coordinate,`(latitude, longitude)`. But this is not happening in reality. I mean

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray  *)locations
```

`should get called only when the device has moved more than 5 meters`.In actuality, the device is stuck with the initial data (the label does not update in the view)..

What am i doing wrong.. Isn't this the right way??

Comment: Does the delegate method gets called at all?

Answer (score 2):

The iPod touch uses WiFi networks for location service. So it may be impossible to get a good location or an update for 5 meter moves?! It ill behave quite different than an iPhone or iPda that also use GPS signals for location.

Comment: So u mean i need to have this running over cellular ip? But shouldn't normal Wifi network be enough.. I mean the device eventually does talk to a data server which in turn pushes the relevant location data..speaking of good location, i did set up the accuracy property to best.. What about the code though?? Shouldn't it solve the intended challenge?..

Comment: The wifi based location service will give a location, yes. But it is rather rough and only gets updated if you move into range of other WiFi nodes. The location then is triangulated. The 5m accuracy you want is only achieved by using GPS chips which the iPod lacks.

Comment: What about an iPad.. I believe it comes with the assisted GPS. Coz the iPhone is GPS + GLONASS enabled..

Comment: iPads can be bought with real GPS, yes

Comment: you mean iPad wifi + cellular versions?? Coz on apple's product page, they do mention GPS under the Cellular and Wireless section for iPhones , but not for iPads.

Comment: Exactly! These come with built in GPS

Comment: So if the triangulation computed location wouldn't cut it for 5m distance filter, how about approximating the location?? Coz when i walk with the iPod touch, it gets moved and the movement spans much more than 5 meters. e.g..if  the device has moved for 20 meters, (giving it a relaxation of 15m in terms approximation) at least then the updation process can kick in. But its not happening even then..The distance filter barrier is 5 meters.. I believe the triangulation procedure can tell 5m and 20m apart. Still its not in actual practice. Is this Ok??

Comment: The granularity of wifi based location services isn't up to the task!

Comment: You can look at [this list of iOS devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices) to see which devices have GPS.  All iPhones have GPS (except iPhone1) and all iPads (except WiFi only iPads) have GPS, no iPod Touches have GPS. Without GPS you will only get 300-1000m accuracy, it requires GPS to get under 100m accuracy and a really good GPS/Glonass signal to get 5m accuracy.